# Setting hex bins in ggplot2 to same size

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to make a hexbin representation of data in several categories. The problem is, facetting these bins seems to make all of them different sizes.

```
set.seed(1) #Create data
bindata <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
fac_probs <- dnorm(seq(-3, 3, length.out=26))
fac_probs <- fac_probs/sum(fac_probs)
bindata$factor <- sample(letters, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=fac_probs)

library(ggplot2) #Actual plotting
library(hexbin)

ggplot(bindata, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_hex() +
  facet_wrap(~factor)
```

[image]

Is it possible to set something to make all these bins physically the same size?

Comment: Usually something like ```+ stat_binhex(binwidth = c(0.5, 0.5))``` in place of ```geom_hex()``` would do the trick but this seems to be ignored when faceting is added. Interestingly it does work when the bins are rectangular ```qplot(x,y, data = bindata, geom = "bin2d", binwidth = c(0.5, 0.5), facets=~factor)```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Julius says, the problem is that `hexGrob` doesn't get the information about the bin sizes, and guesses it from the differences it finds *within the facet*.

Obviously, it would make sense to hand `dx` and `dy` to a `hexGrob` -- not having the width and height of a hexagon is like specifying a circle by center without giving the radius.

### Workaround:

[image: workaround]

The `resolution` strategy works, if the facet contains two adjacent haxagons that differ in both x and y. So, as a workaround, I'll construct manually a data.frame containing the x and y center coordinates of the cells, and the factor for facetting and the counts:

In addition to the libraries specified in the question, I'll need

```
library (reshape2)
```

and also `bindata$factor` actually needs to be a factor:

```
bindata$factor <- as.factor (bindata$factor)
```

Now, calculate the basic hexagon grid

```
h <- hexbin (bindata, xbins = 5, IDs = TRUE, 
             xbnds = range (bindata$x), 
             ybnds = range (bindata$y))
```

Next, we need to calculate the counts depending on `bindata$factor`

```
counts <- hexTapply (h, bindata$factor, table)
counts <- t (simplify2array (counts))
counts <- melt (counts)
colnames (counts)  <- c ("ID", "factor", "counts")
```

As we have the cell IDs, we can merge this data.frame with the proper coordinates:

```
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  ID = h@cell)
hexdf <- merge (counts, hexdf)
```

Here's what the data.frame looks like:

```
> head (hexdf)
  ID factor counts          x         y
1  3      e      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
2  3      s      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
3  3      y      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
4  3      r      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
5  3      p      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
6  3      o      0 -0.3681728 -1.914359
```

`ggplot`ting (use the command below) this yields the correct bin sizes, but the figure has a bit weird appearance: 0 count hexagons are drawn, but only where some other facet has this bin populated. To suppres the drawing, we can set the counts there to `NA` and make the `na.value` completely transparent (it defaults to grey50):

```
hexdf$counts [hexdf$counts == 0] <- NA

ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts)) +
  geom_hex(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~factor) +
  coord_equal () +
  scale_fill_continuous (low = "grey80", high = "#000040", na.value = "#00000000")
```

yields the figure at the top of the post.

This strategy works as long as the binwidths are correct without facetting. If the binwidths are set very small, the `resolution` may still yield too large `dx` and `dy`. In that case, we can supply `hexGrob` with two adjacent bins (but differing in both x and y) with `NA` counts for each facet.

```
dummy <- hgridcent (xbins = 5, 
                    xbnds = range (bindata$x),  
                    ybnds = range (bindata$y),  
                    shape = 1)

dummy <- data.frame (ID = 0,
                     factor = rep (levels (bindata$factor), each = 2),
                     counts = NA,
                     x = rep (dummy$x [1] + c (0, dummy$dx/2), 
                              nlevels (bindata$factor)),
                     y = rep (dummy$y [1] + c (0, dummy$dy  ), 
                              nlevels (bindata$factor)))
```

An additional advantage of this approach is that we can delete all the rows with 0 counts already in `counts`, in this case reducing the size of `hexdf` by roughly 3/4 (122 rows instead of 520):

```
counts <- counts [counts$counts > 0 ,]
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  ID = h@cell)
hexdf <- merge (counts, hexdf)
hexdf <- rbind (hexdf, dummy)
```

The plot looks exactly the same as above, but you can visualize the difference with `na.value` not being fully transparent.

---

## more about the problem

The problem is not unique to facetting but occurs always if too few bins are occupied, so that no "diagonally" adjacent bins are populated.

Here's a series of more minimal data that shows the problem:

First, I trace `hexBin` so I get all center coordinates of the same hexagonal grid that `ggplot2:::hexBin` and the object returned by `hexbin`:

```
trace (ggplot2:::hexBin, exit = quote ({trace.grid <<- as.data.frame (hgridcent (xbins = xbins, xbnds = xbnds, ybnds = ybnds, shape = ybins/xbins) [1:2]); trace.h <<- hb}))
```

Set up a very small data set:

```
df <- data.frame (x = 3 : 1, y = 1 : 3)
```

And plot:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +  geom_hex(binwidth=c(1, 1)) +          
     coord_fixed (xlim = c (0, 4), ylim = c (0,4))

p # needed for the tracing to occur
p + geom_point (data = trace.grid, size = 4) + 
    geom_point (data = df, col = "red") # data pts

str (trace.h)

Formal class 'hexbin' [package "hexbin"] with 16 slots
  ..@ cell  : int [1:3] 3 5 7
  ..@ count : int [1:3] 1 1 1
  ..@ xcm   : num [1:3] 3 2 1
  ..@ ycm   : num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..@ xbins : num 2
  ..@ shape : num 1
  ..@ xbnds : num [1:2] 1 3
  ..@ ybnds : num [1:2] 1 3
  ..@ dimen : num [1:2] 4 3
  ..@ n     : int 3
  ..@ ncells: int 3
  ..@ call  : language hexbin(x = x, y = y, xbins = xbins, shape = ybins/xbins, xbnds = xbnds, ybnds = ybnds)
  ..@ xlab  : chr "x"
  ..@ ylab  : chr "y"
  ..@ cID   : NULL
  ..@ cAtt  : int(0)
```

I repeat the plot, leaving out data point 2:

```
p <- ggplot(df [-2,], aes(x=x, y=y)) +  geom_hex(binwidth=c(1, 1)) +          coord_fixed (xlim = c (0, 4), ylim = c (0,4))
p
p + geom_point (data = trace.grid, size = 4) + geom_point (data = df, col = "red")
str (trace.h)

Formal class 'hexbin' [package "hexbin"] with 16 slots
  ..@ cell  : int [1:2] 3 7
  ..@ count : int [1:2] 1 1
  ..@ xcm   : num [1:2] 3 1
  ..@ ycm   : num [1:2] 1 3
  ..@ xbins : num 2
  ..@ shape : num 1
  ..@ xbnds : num [1:2] 1 3
  ..@ ybnds : num [1:2] 1 3
  ..@ dimen : num [1:2] 4 3
  ..@ n     : int 2
  ..@ ncells: int 2
  ..@ call  : language hexbin(x = x, y = y, xbins = xbins, shape = ybins/xbins, xbnds = xbnds, ybnds = ybnds)
  ..@ xlab  : chr "x"
  ..@ ylab  : chr "y"
  ..@ cID   : NULL
  ..@ cAtt  : int(0)
```

[image: everything fine] [image: hexagon plotting messed up]

- note that the results from `hexbin` are on the same grid (cell numbers did not change, just cell 5 is not populated any more and thus not listed), grid dimensions and ranges did not change. But the plotted hexagons did change dramatically.
- Also notice that `hgridcent` forgets to return the center coordinates of the first cell  (lower left).

Though it gets populated:

```
df <- data.frame (x = 1 : 3, y = 1 : 3)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +  geom_hex(binwidth=c(0.5, 0.8)) +          
     coord_fixed (xlim = c (0, 4), ylim = c (0,4))

p # needed for the tracing to occur
p + geom_point (data = trace.grid, size = 4) + 
    geom_point (data = df, col = "red") + # data pts
    geom_point (data = as.data.frame (hcell2xy (trace.h)), shape = 1, size = 6)
```

[image: all messed up]

Here, the rendering of the hexagons cannot possibly be correct - they do not belong to one hexagonal grid.

Comment: Still no better solution than this workaround? I have the same problem without even using facets.

Answer (score 12):

I tried to replicate your solution with the same data set using lattice `hexbinplot`. Initially, it gave me an error `xbnds[1] < xbnds[2] is not fulfilled`. This error was due to wrong numeric vectors specifying range of values that should be covered by the binning. I changed those arguments in `hexbinplot`, and it somehow worked. Not sure if it helps you to solve it with ggplot, but it's probably some starting point.

```
library(lattice)
library(hexbin)
hexbinplot(y ~ x | factor, bindata, xbnds = "panel", ybnds = "panel", xbins=5, 
           layout=c(7,3))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Although rectangular bins with `stat_bin2d()` work just fine:

```
ggplot(bindata, aes(x=x, y=y, group=factor)) + 
    facet_wrap(~factor) +
    stat_bin2d(binwidth=c(0.6, 0.6))
```

[image]

Comment: Looking into stat_bin2d.R/geom_bin2d.R and stat_binhex.R/geom_bhex.R it turns out that the bin2d ones store xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, whereas the hexagonal ones just have the centers, but not width and height - so geomHex guesses them (as Julian pointed out) and that gets wrong when no diagnonally adjacent facets are in the plot/facet.

Answer (score 5):

There are two source files that we are interested in: [stat-binhex.r](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-binhex.r) and [geom-hex.r](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-hex.r), mainly `hexBin` and `hexGrob` functions.

As @Dinre mentioned, this issue is not really related to faceting. What we can see is that `binwidth` is not ignored and is used in a special way in `hexBin`, this function is applied for every facet separately. After that, `hexGrob` is applied for every facet. To be sure you can inspect them with e.g.

```
trace(ggplot2:::hexGrob, quote(browser()))
trace(ggplot2:::hexBin, quote(browser()))
```

Hence this explains why sizes differ - they depend on both `binwidth` and the data of each facet itself.

It is difficult to keep track of the process because of various coordinates transforms, but notice that the output of `hexBin`

```
data.frame(
  hcell2xy(hb),
  count = hb@count,
  density = hb@count / sum(hb@count, na.rm=TRUE)
)
```

always seems to look quite ordinary and that `hexGrob` is responsible for drawing hex bins, distortion, i.e. it has `polygonGrob`. In case when there is only one hex bin in a facet there is a more serious anomaly.

```
dx <- resolution(x, FALSE)
dy <- resolution(y, FALSE) / sqrt(3) / 2 * 1.15
```

in `?resolution` we can see

> Description
>
> ```
>  The resolution is is the smallest non-zero distance between adjacent
>  values. If there is only one unique value, then the resolution is
>  defined to be one.
> ```

for this reason (`resolution(x, FALSE) == 1` and `resolution(y, FALSE) == 1`) the x coordinates of `polygonGrob` of the first facet in your example are

```
[1] 1.5native  1.5native  0.5native  -0.5native -0.5native 0.5native
```

and if I am not wrong, in this case native units are like npc, so they should be between 0 and 1. That is, in case of single hex bin it goes out of range because of `resolution()`. This function also is the reason of distortion that @Dinre mentioned even when having up to several hex bins.

So for now there does not seem to be an option to have hex bins of equal size. A temporal (and very inconvenient for a large number of factors) solution could begin with something like this:

```
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(2)
bindata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
fac_probs <- c(10, 40, 40, 10)
bindata$factor <- sample(letters[1:4], 100, 
                         replace = TRUE, prob = fac_probs)

binwidths <- list(c(0.4, 0.4), c(0.5, 0.5),
                  c(0.5, 0.5), c(0.4, 0.4))

plots <- mapply(function(w,z){
  ggplot(bindata[bindata$factor == w, ], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_hex(binwidth = z) + theme(legend.position = 'none')
}, letters[1:4], binwidths, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this will not work with very sparsely populated facets. Please verify that your data has the problem with facets. The other way around: all your plots have somewhere "diagonally" adjacent bins populated. In that case, `resolution` gives the correct height and width.

Comment: @cbeleites, I totally agree with you. I just wanted to offer a partial solution where one could input binwidths separately for each factor which could partially solve the problem.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem - not even partially! The binwidth is not handed to `hexGrob` and the problem also occurs without facetting (with facetting the chance to run into the problem is higher, though, because of lower cases per facet). I added some more thorough examples to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I also did some fiddling around with the hex plots in 'ggplot2', and I was able to consistently produce significant bin distortion when a factor's population was reduced to 8 or below.  I can't explain why this is happening without digging down into the package source (which I am reluctant to do), but I can tell you that sparse factors seem to consistently wreck the hex bin plotting in 'ggplot2'.

This suggests to me that the size and shape of a particular hex bin in 'ggplot2' is related to a calculation that is unique to each facet, instead of doing a single calculation for the group and plotting the data afterwards.  This is somewhat reinforced by the fact that I can reproduce the distortion in any given facet by plotting only that single factor, like so:

```
ggplot(bindata[bindata$factor=="e",], aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_hex()
```

This feels like something that should be elevated to the package maintainer, Hadley Wickham (h.wickham at gmail.com).  *This info is publicly available from CRAN.*

**Update**: I sent an email to the Hadley Wickham asking if he would take a look at this question, and he confirmed that this behavior is indeed a bug.

Comment: Thanks for sending that email. @cbeleites filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/762) as well.