# Manually assigning colors with scale_fill_manual only works for certain hexagon sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a scatterplot that is summarized by hexagon bins of counts. I would like the user to be able to define the count breaks for the color scale. I have this working, using `scale_fill_manual()`. Oddly, however, it only works sometimes. In the MWE below, using the given seed value, if `xbins=10`, there are issues resulting in a plot as follows:

[image]

However, if `xbins=20` or `40`, for example, the plot doesn't seem to have problems:

[image]

My MWE is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)
xbins <- 20

x <- abs(rnorm(10000))
y <- abs(rnorm(10000))
minVal <- min(x, y)
maxVal <- max(x, y)
maxRange <- c(minVal, maxVal)
buffer <- (maxRange[2] - maxRange[1]) / (xbins / 2)
h <- hexbin(x = x, y = y, xbins = xbins, shape = 1, IDs = TRUE,
            xbnds = maxRange, ybnds = maxRange)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy(h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
my_breaks <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 1000)
clrs <- brewer.pal(length(my_breaks) + 3, "Blues")
clrs <- clrs[3:length(clrs)]
hexdf$countColor <- cut(hexdf$counts, breaks = c(0, my_breaks, Inf), 
                        labels = rev(clrs))

ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y, hexID = hexID, fill = countColor)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = levels(hexdf$countColor)) +
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) + 
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2] + buffer)), 
              ylim = c(-0.5, (maxRange[2] + buffer))) + 
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

My goal is to tweak this code so that the plot does not have problems (where suddenly certain hexagons are different sizes and shapes than the rest) regardless of the value assigned to xbins. However, I am puzzled what may be causing this problem for certain xbins values. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I am updating the example code after taking into account comments by @bdemarest and @Axeman. I followed the most popular answer in the link @Axeman recommends, and believe it is more useful when you are working with `scale_fill_continuous()` on an integer vector. Here, I am working on `scale_fill_manual()` on a factor vector. As a result, I am still unable to get this goal to work. Thank you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
library(RColorBrewer)

set.seed(1)
xbins <- 10

x <- abs(rnorm(10000))
y <- abs(rnorm(10000))
minVal <- min(x, y)
maxVal <- max(x, y)
maxRange <- c(minVal, maxVal)
buffer <- (maxRange[2] - maxRange[1]) / (xbins / 2)
bindata = data.frame(x=x,y=y,factor=as.factor(1))

h <- hexbin(bindata, xbins = xbins, IDs = TRUE, xbnds = maxRange, ybnds = maxRange)

counts <- hexTapply (h, bindata$factor, table)
counts <- t (simplify2array (counts))
counts <- melt (counts)
colnames (counts)  <- c ("factor", "ID", "counts")
counts$factor =as.factor(counts$factor)

hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  ID = h@cell)
hexdf <- merge (counts, hexdf)

my_breaks <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 1000)
clrs <- brewer.pal(length(my_breaks) + 3, "Blues")
clrs <- clrs[3:length(clrs)]
hexdf$countColor <- cut(hexdf$counts, breaks = c(0, my_breaks, Inf), labels = rev(clrs))

ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = countColor)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = levels(hexdf$countColor)) +
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, color = "red", size = 0.25) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.5, maxRange[2]+buffer), ylim = c(-0.5, maxRange[2]+ buffer)) + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

Comment: I've noticed that this code: `aes(hexID = hexID)` doesn't do anything. The plot is the same if you remove it.

Comment: Your proposition seems incorrect, the same problem occurs when not assigning manual colors.

Comment: That being said, most of this pain can be avoided by using `scale_fill_distiller` and setting `fill = counts`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting hex bins in ggplot2 to same size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495111/setting-hex-bins-in-ggplot2-to-same-size)

Comment: @Aron Thanks for the comment. I added an Edit to show where I believe my code is different than the link you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define colors in 'geom' instead of 'scale' that modifies the scale of plot:

```
ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_hex(stat = "identity",fill =hexdf$countColor)
```

Comment: I am happy to see that component can be fixed. I opened another related post because this solution solves the hexagon size consistency issue but looses the legend. If anyone is interested in more about this, please see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636473/consistent-hexagon-sizes-and-legend-for-manually-assignment-of-colors).